# Delete *.txt files by date between MMDDYYYY and MMDDYYYYY

Tags: files, timestamps

How can I use `rm` to delete *.txt files between MMDDYYYY and MMDDYYYY ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload age
rm -f -- *.txt(D.e{age 2014/03/20 2014/03/30})
```

With GNU or FreeBSD find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -type f -newermt 20140320 \
                                       ! -newermt 20140330 -delete
```

That's for files modified between 2014-03-20 00:00:00 and 2014-03-30 00:00:00.

Comment: Hint for future reader: use `-ls` instead of `-exec rm -f {} +` initially to check whether you have the correct filelist, in order to prevent emotional damage in case of a mistake with the dates.